# what does "hold off" mean

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I updated my colleague about a travel subscription confirmation. And he said 
"Great News! Hold off on arranging travel until I hear from Bill today." I got the point - Dont arrange any travel. But I want to know how else can we use Hold off in different or similar situations.

Comment: Hold off: (usage notes) http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hold-off

Comment: Or [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hold+off) ***hold off*** 2. To stop or delay doing something: *Let's **hold off** until we have more data.* I think this is General Reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some examples. Let's hope that the rain will hold off until we get back home. We should hold off buying that until the price comes down. We'll hold off having sex until we are married. I hope the lion will hold off until we drive away.

Right now, I can't think of any other fundamentally different way of using "hold off".